# Python - Unsupported type(s) : range and range

Tags: python, range, operand

I'm getting this strange error trying to run a script, the code appears to be correct but it seems python (3) didn't liked this part:

```
        def function(x):
                  if integer:
                    return int(x)
                else:
                    return x

            non_nil = randrange(21)
            d = dict([(randrange(101), Racional(coeff(randrange(-20,20)),
                                    coeff(choice(range(-30,0)+\
                                                 range(1,30)))))
                     for k in range(non_nil)])
```

And i get the following error:

```
for k in range(non_nil)]) unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'
```

I already tried to put the last four lines in a single one but python returns the same error.

Comment: What is the intention of ``range(-30, 0) + range(1, 30)``? Why not ``range(-30, 30)``?

Comment: @Lattyware: The range shouldn't include 0, apparently.

Comment: How did I not see that? Disregard that then.

Answer (score 34):

This is because Python 3 `range` does not return a `list`, unlike Python 2.  This code was written for Python 2.

This code should be changed:

```
range(-30,0) + range(1,30)
```

It should be changed to:

```
[*range(-30,0), *range(1,30)]
```

Prior to Python 3.5 (2015, [PEP 448 - Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)), you cannot use `*` inside lists, and must write it this way instead (or you may prefer this):

```
list(range(-30,0)) + list(range(1,30))
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out the problem is that in Python 3, `range()` returns an iterator not a list like it does in Python 2.

Here' one workaround: Add something like the following function:

```
def non_zero_range(lower, upper):
    ret = list(range(lower, upper))
    ret.remove(0)
    return ret
```

and then change the second `Racional()` call argument from:

```
coeff(choice(range(-30,0)+range(1,30)))
```

to simply:

```
coeff(choice(non_zero_range(-30,30)))
```

You will have something that would work in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

In the middle of your expression you do `range(-30,0) + range(1,30)`.  This is causing the error because in Python 3 `range()` returns an iterator, not a list like in Python 2.x.

One way to get this to work is to just convert each range to a list before adding:

```
d = dict([(randrange(101), Racional(coeff(randrange(-20,20)),
                                coeff(choice(list(range(-30,0))+
                                             list(range(1,30))))))
         for k in range(non_nil)])
```

Since it seems like you want to just exclude `0` from the `range(-30, 30)`, you could also use `filter(None, range(-30, 30))`.

Alternatively you could use `choice((1, -1)) * choice(range(1, 30))`, which is equivalent to `choice(list(range(-30, 0)) + list(range(1, 30)))`. (**edit**: actually the prior expression will not include -30 in the possibilities, not sure whether or not that is an issue).

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have said, `range()` being an iterator is your problem, however, a simpler (in my view) solution is to generate the list from `-30` to `30` then remove `0`, rather than avoiding it:

```
choice([i for i in range(-30, 30) if i != 0])
```

Naturally, if your ranges were more disparate, this might become unwieldy.