# Converting Range Values to Integers

Tags: python, random, pygame, range

I'm developing a game in pygame where enemy ships will begin off screen then move vertically on the Y-axis towards the player.

However, I'm having a bit of trouble accessing the location of the enemy since it's all relative to a range. I'm not exactly too sure of how to explain it, but here's what I have for the Enemy Class:

```
class EnemyActive(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        enemy_img_list = ['enemyshipone.png', 'enemyshiptwo.png',
                      'enemyshipthree.png','enemyshipfour.png']
        enemy_img = random.choice(enemy_img_list)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(enemy_img)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0,400)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-200,-10)
        self.speed = random.randrange(1,3)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speed

    def getCoord(self):
        return (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
```

So, when I try to access the position using another function, which takes in an (x,y) coordinate:

```
particle_list = particles.create_particles(particle_list,enemy.getCoord())
```

It comes back with an error stating:

**numbers = range(-5, -1) + range(1, 5)**

**TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'**

I'm not going to lie and say that I fully understand the error, but I do see logic behind the reasoning for it. How can I actually get my 'getCoord' function to send the appropriate coordinates?

Comment: If you are using Python 3, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318083/python-unsupported-types-range-and-range

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace so we don't have to guess what happens?

Comment: Does your code implement that line? What do you want it to do? In python 2, `range` returns a list and they would concatenate without error. On python 3, you can `numbers = list(range(-5, -1)) + list(range(1, 5))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python 3, `range` is an lazy sequence, not a list. That is, it produces the values one at a time like a generator(lazy), when asked for, rather than storing them all in memory at once (eageR).

You can't add ranges together because they don't have the method for + defined. `list` does: it concatenates.

We can convert range to a list by calling the list class on it. I.e, `list(range(1, 5))`.

You can either construct two lists and then concatenate them with +, or you can chain together the generators and then create a single list. This is considered better style since it avoids creating an intermediate list.

Eg:

```
from itertools import chain
my_list = list(chain(range(-5, -1), range(1, 5)))
```

Comment: Actually, range objects are not generators but immutable sequences. The rest of the answer looks good.

Comment: You are correct. I'll edit my answer when I get back to my computer.